# Javascript file loads only on homepage, not on other pages (404 not found error)

Tags: functions, 404-error, wp-register-script

I am getting an issue when loading my functions.js file.
On the homepage everything works, and that is because the url is
"www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/theme/myTheme/function.js"

I get 404 error when opening any other page, and that is because from the console I can see that it is trying to get the file from the following url:
"www.mywebsite.com/**contacts**/wp-content/theme/myTheme/function.js"
So it adds the name of the page BEFORE continuing with the right path.

This is how i register and enqueued my scripts in functions.php:

```
function add_scripts() {
    wp_register_style('functions', get_site_url() . '/wp-content/themes/kiropraktik/functions.js', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('functions');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

Comment: By any chance do you have something like `define( 'WP_SITEURL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` in your wp-config? Something is computing your site_url wrong.

Comment: You should also probably be constructing your functions.js URL with [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) too, or [get_template_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) if this is a child theme, but if your site URL is broken then they'll be broken too.

Comment: You should also be using `wp_enqueue_script()` instead of style.